# How to set div height to auto-adjust for background size?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am making a responsive site . my problem is How do I get a div to automatically adjust to the size of the background I set for it without setting a specific height (or min-height) for it?

```
<style>
#master_head{
width:99%;
min-width:640px;
border:1px solid red;
min-height:50px;
background: url(http://nokiaindiacontest.com/ashalcm/images/nokia-asha-Width-banner.png) no-repeat top;
background-size: contain;   
height:540px;
}
</style>

<div id="master_head"> </div>
```

DEMO Link :- http://jsfiddle.net/rushijogle/5fray/2/

Thanx in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gKQ7e/

This will stretch and keep your div to the top and bottom of the browser as its resized.

Remove `height: 540px`

Add:
`position: fixed;`
`top: 0;`
`bottom: 0;`

```
#master_head{
    width:99%;
    min-width:320px;
    border:1px solid red;
    min-height:50px;
    background: url(http://nokiaindiacontest.com/ashalcm/images/nokia-asha-Width-banner.png) no-repeat top;
    background-size: contain;   
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: hi Dirt, but Div height still remain same . it should be decrease when image will decrease

Answer (score 0):

Actually, There is no way to auto adjust div height to auto-adjust for background size using css.

But you can use javascript to do this(after the background image has been loaded).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
</body>

<div id='hello' style="background:url(http://nokiaindiacontest.com/ashalcm/images/nokia-asha-Width-banner.png);">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
window.onload = function() {

    var imageSrc = document
    .getElementById('hello')
    .style
    .backgroundImage
    .replace(/url\((['"])?(.*?)\1\)/gi, '$2')
    .split(',')[0];

    var image = new Image();
    image.src = imageSrc;

    var width = image.width,
    height = image.height;

    document.getElementById('hello').style.height = height+'px';
    document.getElementById('hello').style.width= width+'px';
}
</script>
</html>
```

Anyway, there is still an inefficiency way to do this without javascript,
by including the image under an img tag with the visibility set to hidden:

```
<div id='hello' style="background:url(http://nokiaindiacontest.com/ashalcm/images/nokia-asha-Width-banner.png);">
    <img src="http://nokiaindiacontest.com/ashalcm/images/nokia-asha-Width-banner.png" style="visibility:hidden"/>
</div>
```

### Best Regards:)

Answer (score 0):

I have been dealing with this issue for a while and decided to write a jquery plugin to solve this problem.
This plugin will find all the elements with class "show-bg" (or you can pass it your own selector) and calculate their background  image dimensions.
all you have to do is include this code, mark the desired elements with class="show-bg" and run:

```
 $(document).heightFromBG();
```

Enjoy!

https://bitbucket.org/tomeralmog/jquery.heightfrombg